# pdf-view-mode - pdfs documents are blinking/flickering on scroll

Tags: pdf, pdf-tools

I have small problem with `pdf-tools` - documents in `pdf-view-mode` are flickering/blinking on scroll. I am not well oriented about rendering, refreshing and all this stuff with pdfs. This is not about cursor blinking, etc. Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Do you see this if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`? If so, consider sending a bug report to the maintainer of `pdf-tools`. If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit. The question, so far, is not so complete - please provide a recipe to repro the problem, saying just what you do and see at each step, and what you expected to see instead.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how it works, but it was Windows 10 thing. On Debian 10 I don't have this problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue in Emacs 28.2 with evil-mode. Using [evil-pdf-tools](https://github.com/ThanosApollo/evil-pdf-tools) has solved this issue among others I had with `pdf-tools`.